# How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs

Tags: office365, office365api

I want to get list of folders/emails inside In-Place mailboxes. But both mailbox list and folder list doesn't returns In-Place mailboxes.

This is what I have tried till now:

1. Get mailboxes using following request

Request:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com')
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Users/$entity",
    "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/Users('12637010-f344-4827-9e3b-21218392985d@649b37da-e479-45dc-a099-fda797d7fcee')",
    "Id": "12637010-f344-4827-9e3b-21218392985d@649b37da-e479-45dc-a099-fda797d7fcee",
    "EmailAddress": "someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "DisplayName": "User Name",
    "Alias": "user1",
    "MailboxGuid": "12312312-a498-46d1-93a8-870cd3faffec"
}
```

2. Get folders listing

Request:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users('someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com')/folders?$top=100
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Users('someuser%40somedomain.onmicrosoft.com')/Folders",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('someuser@somedomain.onmicrosoft.com')/Folders('ABCDA3AYxNjE2NjQyLWE0OTgtNDZkMy05M2E4LTg3MGNkM2ZhZmZlYwAuAAAAAACbFtMO1RLxQoChh4quwNSoAQChU257vJJfSLjbblRIqUFSAABgaA9RAAA=')",
        "Id": 'ABCDA3AYxNjE2NjQyLWE0OTgtNDZkMy05M2E4LTg3MGNkM2ZhZmZlYwAuAAAAAACbFtMO1RLxQoChh4quwNSoAQChU257vJJfSLjbblRIqUFSAABgaA9RAAA=',
        "DisplayName": "Clutter",
        "ParentFolderId": "ABCDAAVCNjE2NjQyLWE0OTgtNDZkMy05M2E4LTg3MGNkM2ZhZmZlYwAuAAAAAACbFtMO1RLxQoChh4quwNSoAQChU257vJJfSLjbblRIqUFSAAAAAAEIAAA=",
        "ChildFolderCount": 0,
        "UnreadItemCount": 0,
        "TotalItemCount": 1
    },
    {
.... other folders like Inbox, Conversations, Conversations history etc.
    }]
}
```

Is it possible to get it use Office 365 unified APIs? If not, is there any alternative? If yes, how does In-Place mailboxes are treated by Exchange online; folder-level(doesn't looks like) or at user level mailboxes?

**Note:** I have changed sensitive information in requests and responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get it use Office 365 unified APIs? If not, is there any alternative?

Archive mailboxes (called an In-Place Archive in Exchange Online) are secondary mailboxes that are associated with a user. The Office 365 API does not support accessing to archive mailboxes.

BTW, achieving is a feature of Exchange, the EWS API supports archiving an item, but it does not support listing mails in achieve mailbox either ([Archiving in EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190900(v=exchg.150).aspx)).

For new feature request of Office 365 API, you can consider submitting it on [Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: It is possible to access In-Place Archive through MS Graph API. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{id}/childFolders
Here as id You can use well known folder names. It's archivemsgfolderroot for archive mailbox.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/archivemsgfolderroot/childFolders

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "well-known" folder name

```
ArchiveMsgFolderRoot
```

to access the in-place archive mailbox. 
For example, to get all messages from the Inbox folder inside the in-place archive mailbox use the following query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/ArchiveMsgFolderRoot/childFolders/Inbox/messages
```

Note: it also uses another predefined folder id (`Inbox`)

A bit more details on [how to work with In-Place Archive Mailbox via Graph API](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/02/get-messages-from-archived-mailbox-aka-in-place-archive-using-graph-api)

and a full list of [well-known folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername?view=exchange-ews-api)

Comment: This was possible until March. Now its not. Also, ArchiveMsgFolderRoot is not part of the [well known folder supported by MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I confirm, it is not possible anymore.