# Access In-Place Archive with MS Graph

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

I need to be able to perform mail operations on folders residing in an Exchange Online Archive (also called In-Place Archive) using MS Graph APIs.

I see that in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis) a year ago, that [Jeffrey Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964222/jeffrey-chen) from Microsoft answered that they were not supported for the older Office 365 REST APIs.

I would appreciate it if someone could verify that the same is true for the newer Microsoft Graph APIs?  They are not included in the results for me/mailFolders query and there doesn't appear to be any option to specify a different Exchange store.

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible . Please see the answer by @Denis here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis