# Is it possible to read emails in the In-Place Archive mailbox with API?

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to download emails from In-Place Archive mailbox in office365.

Looks like Outlook API didn't support it last year [How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)

And a recent question regarding Graph API didn't get any response in [Access In-Place Archive with MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030746/access-in-place-archive-with-ms-graph)

Was anyone successful using unmanaged EWS API?

Comment: It is possible to access the In-Place Archive through the MS Graph API. Please see the comment by @Denis here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking into this scenario now and hope to have a solution on MS Graph soon(can't promise any timelines yet).