# How to get messages from archived mailbox using MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I want to get messages from archive mailbox (enabled In-Place Archive) using Graph API. Could you, please, answere me: how I can do it?

I found similar questions but last answer was 1 year ago.
Links to questions:

- [Is it possible to read emails in the In-Place Archive mailbox with API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444043/is-it-possible-to-read-emails-in-the-in-place-archive-mailbox-with-api)
- [How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)
- [Access In-Place Archive with MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030746/access-in-place-archive-with-ms-graph)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ3B3.jpg)

Comment: Where you able to achieve this ?

Comment: It is possible to access the In-Place Archive through the MS Graph API. Please see the comment by @Denis here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "well-known" folder name

```
ArchiveMsgFolderRoot
```

to access the archive mailbox. 
For example, to get all messages from the Inbox folder inside the archived mailbox use the following query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/mailFolders/ArchiveMsgFolderRoot/childFolders/Inbox/messages
```

btw, it uses another predefined folder id (`Inbox`)

A bit more details on [how to work with Archived Mailbox via Graph API](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/02/get-messages-from-archived-mailbox-aka-in-place-archive-using-graph-api)

Answer (score -1):

First, get the mailFolder list for your account.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(' ')/mailFolders(id,displayName)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$select=id%2cdisplayName&$skip=10",
    "value": [
       ...
        {
            "id": "AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLsdfZjg4ODU0YzUwYwAuAAAAAACtqDzk9UzLSpZsdesjndr1AQBNzq1HG8BvRYqBQbPeZSPaAAGdwZCCAAA=",
            "displayName": "archive"
        } 
...
    ]
}
```

Then, use the archive mailboxs's id(**AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLsdfZjg4ODU0YzUwYwAuAAAAAACtqDzk9UzLSpZsdesjndr1AQBNzq1HG8BvRYqBQbPeZSPaAAGdwZCCAAA=** on my test case) to get the messages in root folder and sub-folder. Combine them on you client.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{archive mailbox id}/childFolders/messages
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{ archive mailbox id}/messages
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I need content of archive mailbox, not "archive" folder.

In your case I got items from this folder: [link](http://prntscr.com/lamc11)
But I need to get items from this folder (space): [link](http://prntscr.com/lamcos)

Comment: I have research many docs too, it seems Graph still does not support the  In-Place Archive. You have to submit an feature request in the User Voice or up-vote an existing one. "In-place Archive" is not provided for all Office license, so it should has many limitation('https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-license-requirements-for-Exchange-features-46b6b7c5-c3ca-43e5-8424-1e2807917c99?CorrelationId=185cf2ce-9cd7-43bc-877e-0094d1200f1f&ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ').