# Accessing online ExchangeArchive programmatically through PowerApps etc

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, office365connectors

I'm trying to build a tool in PowerApps that allows less technical users a simple interface (rather than the somewhat clunky outlook search bar) to be able to search, find, assess and save email attachments off old sent emails going back several years. However, I'm only able to access the last 12 months of emails in the primary mailbox, as the organisation I work for archives anything older into the online ExchangeArchive mailbox.

I've been using using the Outlook Connector GetEmailsV3, but that only pulls emails from the primary mailbox (so up to 12 months old).

```
Office365Outlook.GetEmailsV3({folderPath:"Sent Items",searchQuery:"to:some.address@domain.com",fetchOnlyWithAttachment:true,fetchOnlyUnread:false}).value
```

Not specifically PowerApps, but it looks like there used to be API calls that could be used, but these appear to have been closed in March 2020, as discussed in these other SO questions.

[How to get messages from archived mailbox using MS Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991085/how-to-get-messages-from-archived-mailbox-using-ms-graph-api)

[How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)

Does anyone know if there's another method to call emails from the online Exchange Archive, without resorting to asking our IT department to help with this work through running Powershell compliance scripts on exchange?