# In-Place Archive access via Microsoft Graph data connect or content search or other means

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-data-factory

I need to access in-place archive email messages for team members. This was possible via the graph api per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis). However, it doesn't seem to be anymore. But are there other approaches like Microsoft Graph Data Connect or use of Content Search folders?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Graph API or EWS (Exchange Web Services) API!!

Comment: If only I could. See the last comment by Alfredo R. on the last answer of the link I provided.

Comment: Ok, Graph API is out of option now. In such scenario, you can consider the legacy APIs like EWS (Exchange Web Services) or MAPI to access the in-place archive mailbox. If you're using EWS API then make sure you access the wellknownfoldername enum "ArchiveMsgFolderRoot" - this will get you the root of the message folder hierarchy in the archive mailbox.

Comment: Are you sure that it supports ArchiveMsgFolderRoot? I'm set up for Graph and it'll be a ramp-up to switch over to EWS, so am curious if you are sure. Is there perhaps a quick explorer like the graph explorer so I can ensure feasibility? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i worked with EWS in past and it worked. You can try writing a code or test the same with [EWS Editor](https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor) as well :)

Comment: Thanks. We'll try it out and let you know our findings shortly.

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it goes!!

Comment: It works, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227167/discussion-between-dev-and-vince).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ok, Microsoft Graph API is out of option now. In such scenario, you can consider the legacy APIs like EWS (Exchange
  Web Services) or MAPI to access the in-place archive mailbox.
- If    you're using EWS API then make sure you access the
  wellknownfoldername enum "ArchiveMsgFolderRoot" - this will get you
  the root of the message folder hierarchy in the archive mailbox.
- I worked with EWS in past and it worked. You can try writing a code or test the same with [EWS Editor utility](https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor) as well!!