# Fail to message delta encounter error ErrorMailboxMoveInProgress

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using delta requset to track change on M365 mail folders:

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta
```

But I encounter some error for some in-place archive mailfolder (rest are good).

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorMailboxMoveInProgress",
        "message": "Mailbox move in progress. Try again later., The user and the mailbox are in different Active Directory sites.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-21T07:06:41",
            "request-id": "eea2a19f-7ab1-4039-9ecb-4d11fbaeba77",
            "client-request-id": "eea2a19f-7ab1-4039-9ecb-4d11fbaeba77"
        }
    }
}
cache-control →private
client-request-id →eea2a19f-7ab1-4039-9ecb-4d11fbaeba77
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 21 Apr 2021 07:06:40 GMT
preference-applied →odata.track-changes
request-id →eea2a19f-7ab1-4039-9ecb-4d11fbaeba77
retry-after →15
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-ms-ags-diagnostic →{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Korea Central","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"SE1PEPF00000A3F"}}
```

I also check if there is any move progress on exchange online via powershell

```
Get-MoveRequest | Format-List
```

But I got nothing.

1. Will it be a temporary error for this mailbox?
2. Why it does show any on exchange online via powershell's cmd Get-MoveRequest?

thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but did want to drop a line to say you're not alone. Overnight a lot of my automation started failing with the same error when working with EXO.

Comment: Same problem started here!

Comment: For what it's worth, we started seeing the same error message last week as well for Azure Logic Apps using the Exchange connector to Export Emails.  Worked with a Microsoft representative and determined there was a change to Exchange Online that requires us to supply the mailbox name along with the message id to retrieve correctly going forward.  Given the error message and the timing, hope this can help others.

Comment: MS seems to tanslate this into "code": "ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the answer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/accessing-outlook-items-in-a-users-archived-shared-or-delegated-mailboxes-using-microsoft-graph/

note that such cross-mailbox API calls were never supported, and are less performant and more error-prone. (In-Place Archiving mailbox is an additional mailbox that's enabled for a user's primary mailbox.)

I believe the only alternative is using EWS.

see [How to get In-Place archive mailbox in Exchange Online using Office 365 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939501/how-to-get-in-place-archive-mailbox-in-exchange-online-using-office-365-apis)

Comment: after wait for a long time, we decide to change implemetation as EWS to solve this issue, thanks for reply!